# Subgroups of the multiplicative group of a finite field satisfying a certain additive property

Tags: nt.number-theory, finite-fields, additive-combinatorics

Let $G \subseteq \mathbb F_p^*$ be a subgroup. Then $G$ is called almost trivial if $G \cap (2-G)$ consists of the element 1.

Then I am wondering how big $G$ can be in terms of $p$. If $G$ is a random set containing 1 then according to the birthday paradox one expects that $G$ and $2-G$ have nontrivial intersection as soon as $\#G \gg \sqrt p$.

> I am wondering if maybe one could prove that all almost trivial subgroups of $\mathbb
>  F_p^*$ have size at most $\tilde O(\sqrt p)$.

Or if a $\sqrt p$ up to log factors bound is out of reach, I was wondering if there is $1/2 < \epsilon < 1$ and some constant $c$ such that for all almost trivial groups we have $\#G < cp^\epsilon$.

I did some numeric experimentation by finding the largest almost trivial subgroup of $\mathbb F_p^*$ for all p < 80000. And the largest ratio that I could find for $\frac {\#G}{\sqrt p}$ was $\frac {884}{\sqrt {41549}} = 4.3368\ldots$ because $\mathbb F_{41549}$ contains an almost trivial subgroup of order 884, so a square root (possibly up to log factors) bound seams reasonable.

P.S. The notion of being almost trivial is based on the notion of almost rational in the  paper [Almost rational torsion points on semistable elliptic curves by
Frank Calegari](https://doi.org/10.1155/S1073792801000253).

Comment: Every subgroup contains 1 so how can it be 2-complementary?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I rewrote the question significantly to correct the mistake you highlight. For some reason I had the wrong notion of "trivial intersection" in the back of my mind. Strangely enough I did explicitly exclude the element 1 in the code that I wrote.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If we let $S$ be the set of characters of $\mathbb F_p^\times$ trivial on $G$ then $$\sum_{\chi \in S} \chi(g) = \begin{cases} \frac{p-1}{|G|} & g\in G \\ 0 & g\notin G \end{cases}$$

so $$\sum_{\chi_1,\chi_2\in S} \sum_{ g \in \mathbb F_p \setminus \{0,1,2\} } \chi_1(g) \chi_2(2-g)  = 0$$ if $G$ is almost trivial.

Now if $\chi_1 =\chi_2=1$ then $\sum_{ g \in \mathbb F_p \setminus \{0,1,2\} } \chi_1(g) \chi_2(2-g)=p-3$ and otherwise, by the bound for Jacobi sums, $\left| \sum_{ g \in \mathbb F_p \setminus \{0,1,2\} } \chi_1(g) \chi_2(2-g) \right| \leq  \sqrt{p}+1 $.

Thus, if $G$ is almost trivial then $p-3 \leq ( ((p-1)/|G|)^2-1) (\sqrt{p}+1)$,  or $p \leq c^2 p^{5/2} / |G|^2$ for a constant $c$, meaning $|G| \leq c p^{3/4}$, answering the weaker form of your question.

Comment: Are there typos in the inequalities in your last line, especially in terms of the direction of the inequality? It seems to me that the first inequality should read $p-3 \leqslant (m^2 - 1)(\sqrt{p}+1)$ where $m = (p-1)/|G|$?

Comment: @AnuragSahay Yes, good point, fixed or at least improved.